# Cleaning build directory in setup.py

Tags: python, build, distutils

How could I make my `setup.py` pre-delete and post-delete the build directory?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For pre-deletion, just delete it with `distutils.dir_util.remove_tree` before calling setup.

For post-delete, I assume you only want to post-delete after selected commands. Subclass the respective command, override its run method (to invoke remove_tree after calling the base run), and pass the new command into the cmdclass dictionary of setup.

Answer (score 148):

If I remember correctly, you'll need to use the `--all` flag to get rid of stuff outside of `build/lib`:

```
python setup.py clean --all
```

Documentation: [docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.clean](https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/apiref.html#module-distutils.command.clean)

Comment: It seems not all `setup.py` scripts support `clean`.  Example: NumPy

Comment: clean works in my case for some files, but e.g. the .egg directory stays there... any way to "deep clean"?

Comment: ahhh, and in my case there was a makefile, so I could `make clean` from there... (simple module created with cookiecutter)

Comment: Unfortunately this does not also clean the `dist` and `egg-info` directories, so I just made a shell script to `rm -rf ./build ./dist ./*egg-info`, letting PyCharm's run configuration manage the working directory.

Answer (score 13):

This clears the build directory before to install

```
python setup.py clean --all install
```

But according to your requirements: This will do it before, and after

```
python setup.py clean --all install clean --all
```

Comment: Second `clean --all` is being ignored.  I tried the following `python3 ./setup.py clean --all install clean --all` and the `build` directory persists.  In the output, no mention about any cleaning after `install`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an answer that combines the programmatic approach of Martin's answer with the functionality of Matt's answer (a `clean` that takes care of all possible build areas):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.clean import clean
from distutils.command.install import install

class MyInstall(install):

    # Calls the default run command, then deletes the build area
    # (equivalent to "setup clean --all").
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        c = clean(self.distribution)
        c.all = True
        c.finalize_options()
        c.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    setup(
        name="myname",
        ...
        cmdclass={'install': MyInstall}
    )
```

Comment: to simply run a command after another, an "alias" seems like a better solution: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#alias-define-shortcuts-for-commonly-used-commands

Comment: @Florian, I imagine that an alias could be a better solution in some situations. In my situation, however, I generate the setup.py file once for each package I produce. It's only a one-time cost to put the logic in the template that generates the setup.py file.