# Testing Artifactory access locally by refreshing dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gradle, sbt, artifactory

We have intermittent outages in Artifactoy that we are trying to address. I've found that sometimes the issues go unnoticed because many dependencies are already locally cached. So I've been running the falling in our `gradle` java projects:

##### gradle

`./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies`

Would these be equivalent in the various build tools? How would something like this be done for an interpreted language like Python?

##### maven

```java
mvn clean install -U
```

##### sbt

```scala
sbt update
sbt clean
sbt compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like performing dependencies cleanup was answered in the following answer:
[Cleaning build directory in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594827/cleaning-build-directory-in-setup-py)